# How to load network images on flutter web?

Tags: flutter

I made a flutter app that runs perfectly fine on Android Virtual Device but doesn't run properly when I try to run it on Edge/Chrome. Flutter is unable to load network images on web, and throws an error:

```
════════ Exception caught by image resource service ════════════════════════════
Failed to load network image.
Image URL: https://www.dpreview.com/files/p/articles/4059075864/images/front.jpeg
Trying to load an image from another domain? Find answers at:
https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/web-images
```

And the image on Chrome looks like this:

[image]

So far, I have read some articles on StackOverflow and they all suggest running the HTML renderer but in my case, it didn't work.
The code I use to load the image is:

```
Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    color: Colors.white,
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
  ),
  child: FadeInImage.memoryNetwork(
    placeholder: kTransparentImage,
    image:
      Data().shopItems[index]['image'].toString(),
  ),
),
```

How to load network images on web?

Comment: do you control the domain where images are hosted?

Comment: @ChrisGhenea No I dont control the domain

Comment: ok. The error that you see has a link in it: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/web-images#cross-origin-images There are some solutions there. There are different things that you could do, depending on your setup

Comment: @ChrisGhenea The solutions in the link didn't work either, do you think if I download the images and host them myself would work?

Comment: yes, downloading the images should work

Answer (score 0):

flutter run -d chrome --web-renderer html
will fix the issue but looses the performanc